# Does Chrome for Mac mess with the gamma level?

Tags: google-chrome, images

Images displayed in Google Chrome for Mac (5.0.375.99) appear washed out, in comparison with images displayed in Mozilla Firefox 3.6 or Apple Safari 5.

Does Google Chrome do something weird with images, like set the gamma to match Windows displays? How would I disable this, so that Chrome uses my global display preferences?

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running? From v10.6 (Snow Leopard) it uses the same gamma (2.2) as Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Google Chrome for Mac (10.0.648.151 beta) and Mac OS X 10.6.7 work well together, enough so that gamma issues are fixed and now I can see images in bright, rich colors.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't currently support embedded ICC colour profiles unlike Safari or Firefox so it's possible there's something going on there. Have a look at the examples in this [colour management tutorial](http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't possible, but is a feature that more people than just you are [clamoring](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3de2ee5284399d84&hl=en) for.